# Options for PayPal Payouts with Bank

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments, paypal-rest-sdk

I'm looking for a way to pay users to their PayPal account - ideally without manual intervention. I've looked at the MassPay & Payout APIs,  but it seems that I need to hold the balance to be paid out in my PayPal account and there is no way to add funds to the PayPal account via the API.

I've also looked at the AdaptivePay API with the implicit payment option. However it fails to mention

1.) If I need to have the funds in the PayPal or if it will do an transfer from my primary banking source.

2.) What the fees for the transaction are? AFAIK it seems like payments can be made for free which would be strange considering the Payout API requires a fee.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adaptive API with implicit payment will transfer the fund from the primary bank if balance cannot cover it, and implicit payment transaction fees is the same as normal transactions. MassPay & Payout APIs are usually used to send money to like hundreds of users while implicit payment can send money to 9 users at one time.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - but 1.) If payments are made from the bank, then I'm assuming there are no fees then as there are no fees on bank to user payments. 2.) Is there a limit on the number of implicit payments I can make?

Comment: There will be fees no matter the funds are from bank or any other source as long as you use PayPal API to transfer the money. You can may implicit payment API calls as much as you want, there's no number limit. But be careful not to make it too frequent in very short time (say 20 times in 15 seconds) since it may trigger PayPal's rate limit rule